# Live in NY but work remotely for a company in Virginia. Which 529 plan can I deduct taxes?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, new-york, 529-plan, virginia

I live in NY and I just started working remotely for a company in Virginia.  I will not be moving to Virginia.

I've been contributing to my NY 529 plan since I can get a state tax deduction on it.  Now that I work for a company in Virginia, not sure if this is possible anymore.  I looked at Virginia's 529 plan and they also provide a state tax deduction.  Which one should I be contributing to if I want to get a state tax deduction?

Comment: Your income is considered earned in NY. I'd continue to contribute to the NY 529 - you're not going to be owing any Virginia taxes.